# Jquery Cycle2 non-image div position issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to do a slideshow full of information that will need to be placed in different areas of a container.

My problem is that the div of the cycle 2 slideshow seems to be ignoring the position specified in the style.

Is it because cycle2 is made to ignore position of the child div? Or I am missing something?

My image slide show works like charm.. if I could just get this going.

```
<div style="position:relative; left:459px; height:306px; width:565px;">
  <div class="cycle-slideshow" 
    data-cycle-slides="> div"
    data-cycle-pager="#pager"
    data-cycle-pager-template=""        
    >
     <div style="position:absolute; height:20px; left:200px;">
        <font style="color: #ffffff; font-family: 'Great Vibes', ClearType ; font-size: 10pt; font-smooth:always; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;">Lorem ipsum dolor ...</font>
    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute; height:20px; left:200px; ">
        <font style="color: #ffffff; font-family: 'Great Vibes', ClearType ; font-size: 20pt; font-smooth:always; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;">Lorem ipsum dolor ...</font>
    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute; height:20px; left:200px;">
        <font style="color: #ffffff; font-family: 'Great Vibes', ClearType ; font-size: 30pt; font-smooth:always; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;">Lorem ipsum dolor ...</font>
    </div>               
  </div>
</div>
```

The css of the cycle-slideshow is pretty basic:

```
.cycle-slideshow {
width: 200px; 
margin: 0;
 }
```

Thank you in advance for all your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

If it might help someone in the future, I actually enclosed my text in a  with it's position detailed and it worked.